# PHP code to extract data from html page including tags

Tags: php

I've searched and tested for hours, ready to give up.
I have a html page that will change every now and then, it's structure is this....

```
100 or so lines of HTML
<div class="the start of the info I want">
500 lines of HTML that I want to extract
<div class="end of the info I want">
more lines of HTML
```

This is my code that does not work, well one of many I've tried.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.soemstupidsite.xyz');
$regex = '#<div class="the start of the info I want">(.*?)<div
class="end of the info I want">#';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
print_r($match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

Returns the following error:
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/www/mycrapcode.php on line 7

What the hell am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($match)` to see what it returns

Comment: I assume the offset error is because the array is empty which is what print_r($match); shows.

Comment: `echo $match[1];` this line throws the *NOTICE*, because the array  `$match` is empty.

Comment: Yes I stated that above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $regex = '/<div class="the start of the info I want">(.*?)<div
class="end of the info I want">/s';
```

Comment: Wow, one rotten "s" missing. That fixed it. Thank you so much. If you are ever in the Aussie outback look me up I owe you a beer mate!

Answer (score 0):

Please read something more about the regex modifiers/flags [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

The flag you need, is the `s` flag, so your selector would work on multiple lines.

Example with your code:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.soemstupidsite.xyz');
$regex = '#<div class="the start of the info I want">(.*?)<div class="end of the info I want">#s';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
print_r($match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

Also: the regex needs to be on 1 line, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: regex is on one line it wrapped when pasted. Thanks for the explanation of the 's' flag. Alexandr Malyita beat you by 6 minutes for the answer I've been looking for for half a day. I'll spot you a beer too if you're ever out my way!